# Passing an array inside Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension

My extension has a background.html which gets some information and then it redirects to another web page whose css is modified by my javascript file (app.js).
So now I'm trying to pass an array from a background.html to that javascript file, both in the same extension folder. I tried the [example](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) but I had no success. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

When I was working on an extension that needed to pass lots of information back and forth between the background and the js file I found it was simplest to create a var like this

```
 const Background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()
```

and then whenever I needed to access anything on the background page I could just use the . operator. like this

```
 Background.foo() //access a function on background page.
 Background.my_var // access a variable on the background page.
 Background.my_array[0] // access the 0 index in your background array
```

Since the background page did not need to know what was in the js file most of the time it was simply easier to use:

```
 popups[0].foo()
```

If it needed to access something in the popup or the js files.

Comment: That "chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()" it's not working for me. I have in manifest "background_page": "background.html" so I don't understand why it doesn't pass in that function. But if I use that function in background.html it passes, but not in my javascript file.

Comment: have you included your javascript file in your popup.html page?

Comment: If I do that, the Javascript won't work because it's like it already was executed. I put in JS file const background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
alert(background.token); and when I run my extension e gives an alert "undefined" and the page hasn't arrive to the redirect page yet.

Comment: why are you doing an alert on `(background.token)` ? either just `alert(background)` or do a `console.log(background)` and if you include your js file after the end of the html in the popup.html file then you don't run into that issue of it thinking its already executed. if you use `console.log(background)` then when you go to run your program right click on the icon and inspect popup then bring up the console inside the pane it gives you.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your background page

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://yourdomain.com"}, function (tab){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, file: "app.js", function(){
        //This is a Callback
    });
});
```